# Windows Phone dependent async requests

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, asynchronous, windows-phone-8, hammock

I have a windows phone 7 app. I have a pivot control. I'm making a RestRequest (Hammock library) to get the async web result to fill first pivot item. I want to make a second request as soon as I get first result without hanging up the UI. It must show the first pivot content while doing a background request for second pivot content. I'm getting error for the second request.

[image]

Comment: That image does not help, please provide code/xaml being used

Answer (score 0):

**Async** methods return `Task` objects. Read about `Task.ContinueWith` construction, which allows to set asynchronous methods flow in queue.